# How does interfaces get Equals and other methods defined in Object class

Tags: c#

Code sample:

```
List<ITest> tests = new List<ITest>();
tests.Add(new Test());
tests.Add(new Test());

Console.WriteLine(tests[0].Equals(tests[1]));
```

I came to know that in Java the public instance methods in Object classes get inserted into interface definition at compile time; Is this the behavior in C# also?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806020/c-what-does-the-operator-do-in-detail/806027#806027

Answer (score 0):

The same happens in C#: `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are methods implemented in the `System.Object` class. Your own classes can – but don’t always need to – override them.

Like in Java, the default `object` implementation performs reference equality (for `class`es). I.e. the following holds for two objects `a` and `b`: `a.Equals(b)` implies `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` (but not vice-versa, since `a` can be `null`). `GetHashCode` is implemented to match this behaviour.

For `struct`s the situation is slightly different: `Equals` by default tries to compare all fields in the `struct` for pairwise equality.

Comment: I was looking for reason behind how 'Equals' and other methods that are part of Object class are available in interface refereces

Comment: @Krishna: well, interfaces in .NET are reference types so although this seems quite wacky, they are derived from `System.Object` in that regard.

Comment: Thanks; are you sure about this; is there was I can verify this using ILDASM or some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Krishna, while your List is a list of ITest, you are adding Test objects, which inherit from System.Object. 
Try to override Equals in your Test object and put a logging statement if you doubt that.